# syntax group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, max, aggregate-functions

I need to calculate the performance which is the maximum mileage of the month of July minus the maximum mileage of the month of August, try this query which works but only prints the same amount.

this is my query:

```
select vehicle_id, max(odometro) as cierre,sum(cantidad) as lts,((select max(odometro) 
      from vehicle_consumptions where fecha between '2020-07-01' and '2020-07-31' group by vehicle_id) - (select max(odometro) from vehicle_consumptions where fecha between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-30' group by vehicle_id))
       as recorrido,
       ((select max(odometro) 
      from vehicle_consumptions where fecha between '2020-07-01' and '2020-07-31') - 
      (select max(odometro) from vehicle_consumptions where fecha between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-30'))/sum(cantidad) as rendimiento
        from vehicle_consumptions where EXTRACT(month from fecha)= 08 group by vehicle_id
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select vehicle_id,
    max(case when fecha < '2020-08-01' then odometro end)
        - max(case when fecha >= '2020-08-01' then odometro end)
    as odometro_diff
from vehicle_consumptions 
where fecha between '2020-07-01' and '2020-08-31'
group by vehicle_id
```

In Postgres, we can use the standard `filter` clause and date literals (assuming that `fecha` is of a date-like datatype - as it should be):

```
select vehicle_id,
    max(odometro) filter(fecha < date '2020-08-01')
        - max(odometro) filter(where fecha >= date '2020-08-01')
    as odometro_diff
from vehicle_consumptions 
where fecha between date '2020-07-01' and date '2020-08-31'
group by vehicle_id
```

Finally: if your dates have time components, I would recommend half-open intervals, so the `where` clause should be:

```
where fecha >= date '2020-07-01' and fecha < '2020-09-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select vehicle_id,
       (max(case when fecha between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31' then odometro end)
        max(case when fecha between '2020-07-01' and '2020-07-31' then odometro end)
       ) as diff 
from vehicle_consumption
group by vehicle_id;
```

In Postgres, you can formulate this as:

```
select vehicle_id,
       (max(odometro) filter (where extract(month from fecha) = 7) -
        max(odometro) filter (where extract(month) from fecha) = 8)
       ) as diff 
from vehicle_consumption
where fecha >= '2020-07-01' and fecha < '2020-09-01'
group by vehicle_id;
```

The `where` clause limits the processing to only two months, which should make the query perform better.  It then just uses the month to filter the `max()`.